# TYPO3 - How to display form in grid element?

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-10.x, tx-gridelements

I use TYPO3 v10.4.8 with the extension gridelements and the core form extension. I have included the form into my created grid element in the backend, but it's not visible in frontend. This is a part of my grid template:

```
<f:if condition="{children}">
    <f:for each="{children}" as="columns" key="rowNumber">
        <div class="row grid-row grid-row-{rowNumber}">
            <f:if condition="{columns}">
                <f:for each="{columns}" as="column" key="columnNumber">
                    <div class="col-12 grid-column grid-column-{columnNumber}">
                        <f:for each="{column}" as="child">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="tt_content.{child.data.CType}" data="{child.data}" table="tt_content" />
                            </div>
                        </f:for>
                    </div>
                </f:for>
            </f:if>
        </div>
    </f:for>
</f:if>
```

My configuration:

```
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup =< lib.contentElement
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup {
    templateName.field = tx_gridelements_backend_layout
    templateName.ifEmpty = GridElement
  layoutRootPaths {
    10 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    20 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
  }
  partialRootPaths {
    10 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Partials/
    20 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
  }
  templateRootPaths {
    10 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Templates/
    20 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
  }
  dataProcessing {
    10 = GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\DataProcessing\GridChildrenProcessor
    10 {
      default {
        as = children
        options {
            resolveChildFlexFormData = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `Render.html` file from the core module is called, but the variable `formConfiguration` is empty, so no form is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a form element uses the `pi_flexform` field to select the form definition, you have to disable the automatic FlexForm resolver of Gridelements.

By default Gridelements with dataProcessing is meant to be rendering everything within a FLUID template by accessing variables and settings directly. So the default setting of the DataProcessor is to resolve FlexForm XML data into arrays.

To disable that behaviour you can use the option

```
resolveFlexFormData = 0
```

to disable it for a container and its children or

```
resolveChildFlexFormData = 0
```

to still resolve container FlexForms but skip those of child elements.

Comment: I changed the configuration as described, but unfortunately the form is not displayed.

Comment: Could you post the configuration here please?

Comment: I added the configuration to my question

Comment: The parameter uses upper camel case, so it is resolveChildFlexFormData, not resolveChildFlexformData. Additionally you should check, if those settings actually arrive at

tt_content.gridelements_pi1

since lib.gridElements.defaultGridSetup would be just a library that has to be assigned to the actual tt_content definition.

Comment: Camel case was not the problem because I copied your solution, but in the meantime I must have entered it wrong during testing: sorry for that.
The configuration was missing in tt_content.gridelements_pi1, I added it and now it works. Thanks for your help.